# How to create a Branch from TFS project (from a labelled version)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, branching-and-merging

How can I create a branch from a TFS project based on a specific label?

I need to create branch from a TFS project that too only from a labelled version. I could see in the new project creation wizard that I can choose the project as a branch to an existing one. 
However I could only do that for the latest version of main branch.

There is no option provided to branch from a label.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just create an empty new team project in the same Project Collection. Then you can use the standard Branch feature in Visual Studio to branch over the exact labeled version you want.

The Create Project wizard doesn't have this feature, but the end result is exactly what you want. You can enter the target branch name as `$/Other-Project/TargetFolder`

[image: Branch from label after project creation]

Comment: I tried this. When I try to branch that to the new project, it has thrown TF10169: unsupported pending change attempted on team project folder $/newBranch

Comment: Also I am trying to branch "Nordics-Trainers" to a new pRoject. Thats my requirement..

Comment: If the team project already has a branch in it, you must branch over each branch individually. You can't branch over to a new project from the root level.

Comment: Ok.. My root project(ex: Nordics-Trainers) has no branches. I achieved in this way. I created a new project(ex:Nordics-Branches) and branched source to a folder under new project(ex: Target is "$\Nordics-Branches\Br01").Because I could not directly branch to a project.   Similarly i can create as many branches as different folders.

Answer (score 1):

After talking with an MS rep I have discovered that this is a straight up BUG! You cannot create a branch using VS2013 and TFS2012. You will either need to have VS2012 or Team Explorer 2012 to do this on your machine. This is absolutely ridiculous. Nice job MS.

Comment: just found out the hardway.. overwrote my main files when checking in from "branch" what a bollache!